# Cannot access docker container exposed port. Can ping but cannot telnet

Tags: docker, networking

I am trying to create an apache container in docker by following below link:

> https://www.assistanz.com/installing-apache-web-server-in-windows-container-using-docker-file/

Version Details:

Host OS: Windows Server 2016 (VMWare virtualized machine)

Docker Version:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-16
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.7
 Git commit:   9ef4f0a
 Built:        Thu Jul 26 16:43:19 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.06.2-ee-16
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.8.7
  Git commit:   9ef4f0a
  Built:        Thu Jul 26 16:52:17 2018
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

I managed to create the container and run it with below command:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 apache powershell

PS C:\> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Container NIC 258c52dd):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::706a:94f1:9a6:6c49%31
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.60.107
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.48.1
```

Confirm if the apache is running on port 80 from inside of the container:

```
PS C:\> iwr http://localhost -usebasicparsing

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```

From host machine:

- Access http://container-ip:80 and failed

  ```
  PS C:\Windows\system32> iwr http://172.21.60.107:80 -usebasicparsing
  iwr : Unable to connect to the remote server
  ```
- Access http://host-ip:8080 and failed

  ```
  PS C:\Windows\system32> iwr http://192.168.105.87:8080 -usebasicparsing
  iwr : Unable to connect to the remote server
  ```

Tried to access from other pc using http://host-ip:8080 and also failed.

Few things that i did for troubleshooting:

1. Check container port forwarding by running docker ps

   ```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
    8bdaf5b11ab9        apache              "powershell"        14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   inspiring_turing
   ```
2. Check Static Mapping by running Get-NetNatStaticMapping

   ```
   PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetNatStaticMapping


   StaticMappingID               : 3
   NatName                       : Hf41327a7-ce0a-464c-83ff-21223867c9ea
   Protocol                      : TCP
   RemoteExternalIPAddressPrefix : 0.0.0.0/0
   ExternalIPAddress             : 0.0.0.0
   ExternalPort                  : 8080
   InternalIPAddress             : 172.21.60.107
   InternalPort                  : 80
   InternalRoutingDomainId       : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   Active                        : True
   ```
3. Ensure again that Firewall and Antivirus are disabled
4. Ensure there is no proxy

   ```
   PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"


   DisableCachingOfSSLPages : 1
   IE5_UA_Backup_Flag       : 5.0
   PrivacyAdvanced          : 1
   SecureProtocols          : 2688
   User Agent               : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Win32)
   CertificateRevocation    : 1
   ZonesSecurityUpgrade     : {75, 36, 102, 206...}
   WarnonZoneCrossing       : 0
   EnableNegotiate          : 1
   MigrateProxy             : 1
   ProxyEnable              : 0
   PSPath                   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
   PSParentPath             : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
   PSChildName              : Internet Settings
   PSProvider               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
   ```
5. Check container network

   ```
   PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ContainerNetwork

   Name Id                                   Subnets          Mode SourceMac DNSServers DNSSuffix
   ---- --                                   -------          ---- --------- ---------- ---------

   nat  f41327a7-ce0a-464c-83ff-21223867c9ea {172.21.48.0/20} NAT
   ```
6. Ping container IP from host => Okay
7. Telnet to container IP and Port from host => Failed

   ```
   PS C:\Windows\system32> telnet 172.21.60.107 80
   Connecting To 172.21.60.107...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed
   ```
8. Ping host IP from container => Failed

Have googled this issue and tried a lot of troubleshooting but seems like i could not find the solution for my issue. Most of the issue reported is due to the localhost loopback issue in window.

Any pointer on how to troubleshoot this further?

I am suspecting there is something blocking the container port. But i cant find it.

Thanks

Comment: did you checked with http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: @Nobita Yeah, i did try that but it's not working also. But i guess this is due to windows WinNat limitation issue. But i would expect i can access from container-ip:80